# What's the difference between APNs Distribution iOS and Apple Push Services?

Tags: ios, push-notification

[image]

As the picture shows, when I want to create the Production SSL Certificate，the normal type should be [APNs Distribution iOS], but the Certificate i've created was [Apple Push Services], what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The "Apple Development iOS Push Services" and "Apple Production iOS Push Services" are the **old names** for the certificate when you needed to have separate certificates for the two environments.

Now, you only need the one certificate for the **new HTTP/2 API**, so they've changed the name of the certificate to something more general - "Apple Push Services".

There's some good info on it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20180201122153/https://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2015/06/17/wwdc-2015-apple-push-goes-http2-for-apns/

Apple's official documentation here (at the time of this answer):
https://web.archive.org/web/20150701004738/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Apple's official documentation (2023):
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns

WWDC 2015 "What's New in Notifications" video here:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-720/

You therefore shouldn't now be able to create certificates for the two separate environments. One of the major benefits of this is that the certificate that works for "debug" builds of your app (mainly those installed directly onto the device via cable) will also work for builds that you send to your testers, and also for production builds.

Comment: That means that we only need **3 certificates per app** now. The Apple Push Services one, the iOS Development one and the iOS distribution one. Maybe in 15 years they'll narrow it down to 1, like on other platforms.

Comment: there is just one valid link (WWDC 15'), other links are invalid

Comment: Updated links - for original links they now point to valid web archives; added current link for Push documentation in 2023

Answer (score 11):

Looks like now production certificates work in the development environment too (but not vice versa). So that's why Apple changed the name of the production certificate to something generic: *Apple Push Services:...*

Comment: That is correct the production certificate works fine in development environment.

Answer (score 9):

Their is a big difference between “Apple Development iOS Push Services” and “Apple Production iOS Push Services” certificates . One is used for sandbox and the other is used for the production push server. Make sure you use the appropriate certificate for testing and production and do not confuse with those

The two kind of push SSL certificates as you have mention above i.e Development and Production. Development push SSL certificate will only work if you attach your iPhone with your mac and directly compile on your device. When you use Development Push SSL certificate Apple's demo server will be used to send notifications. Whereas when you create the app file or .ipa file and install that on device you need to use production push SSL certificate. You can not mix and match these certificate.

Hope it will clear your doubt... :)

Comment: No it's not. The question is about the difference between "Apple production IOS push service" (The old name) and "Apple push services". This answer is true for other question.

Comment: Thanks, helpful. Thus, I assume that I did correctly set up my environment if I only receive notification from "development" server when I install the app through Xcode directly to my device.

Comment: However, now you can only use the production certificate with both URLs.