# Twilio Error - 52134 Invalid APNs device token

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, voip

I've upload my app on TestFlight and trying to make voice call using twilio and it's throwing **Error - 52134 Invalid APNs device token**. I've been reading a lot of tutorials on fixing it but despite all my effort I've been able to fix. In sandbox it worked fine though.

I've done followings:
1) Created a new .certSigningRequest from keychain access

2) Generated new VoIP Services Certificate using above on https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/distribution/create

3) Added certificate in keychain, Exported .p12 file from keychain

4) Followed instructions on https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift to run those three commands to generate key and cert

5) On twilio created a new Push Credential and added Certificate and key by copying and pasting

6) SANDBOX is unticked

7) Change CREDENTIAL SID in my server backend

8) Restarted server

I'm using automatic manage signing so I'm assuming everything should be alright there.

Regarding "APS Environment: production", I'm assuming xCode will make it production automatically when uploaded on TestFlight. I can see that it is included.

Despite all of above I'm still getting this freaking error APS Environment: production

I'm aware that the solution of this problem, in 99% cases, is to regenerate cert but right now I'm stuck. I've tried it two times already.

Not sure what else I can do to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have created a production certificate? That is, it starts with "Apple Push Services" and not "Apple Development IOS Push Services"?

Comment: You mean the VoIP certificate on apple developer site? Yes that's production. See my question I've added screenshot. Is that correct?

Comment: Would you be able to [contact Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide the Credential SID as well as this description. The team will be able to look at the credentials and see if they can spot anything wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Already did, hope someone will find time to look into ticket.

Comment: "it starts with "Apple Push Services" and not "Apple Development IOS Push Services"?" Which file to check it? The VoIP certificate downloaded from developer account, the .cer file? There is no such line in this file.

Comment: I think these lines are applicable to Push Services and not for VoIP services? And according to this reply this is no longer applicable https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645795/10733471

Comment: Yeah, think you might be right. Sorry to be misleading. Twilio support will likely be more helpful than me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i followed this way. it works for both sandbox and live.

To Create Twilio Certificate. follow this instructions.

STEP 1:

```
1. An Apple Developer membership to be able to create the certificate.
2. Make sure your App ID has the “Push Notifications” service enabled.
3. Create a corresponding Provisioning Profile for your app ID.
4. Create an Apple VoIP Services Certificate for this app by navigating to Certificates -> Production and clicking the + on the  top right to add the new certificate (choose voip cert at the bottom).
5. Download the certificate, export the .p12 from keychain.
```

STEP 2:
Then follow these steps, by navigating to the folder where you added your .p12.

```
1. openssl pkcs12 -in liveVoip.p12 -nocerts -out key.pem
2. openssl rsa -in key.pem -out key.pem
3. openssl pkcs12 -in liveVoip.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem
4. openssl pkcs12 -in liveVoip.p12 -out VOIP.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

in Twillio console, Go to the Push Credentials page and create a new Push Credential. Paste the certificate and private key extracted from your certificate. You must paste the keys in as plaintext:

```
For the cert.pem you should paste everything from -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- to -----END CERTIFICATE-----.
For the key.pem you should paste everything from -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- to -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----.
```

Remember to check the “Sandbox” option. This is important. The VoIP Service Certificate you generated can be used both in production and with Apple's sandbox infrastructure. Checking this box tells Twill to send your pushes to the Apple sandbox infrastructure which is appropriate with your development provisioning profile.

Once the app is ready for store submission, update the plist with “APS Environment: production” and create another Push Credential with the same VoIP Certificate but without checking the sandbox option

STEP 3: To test that your app receives notification, get the device token, open terminal, go to the folder where you added .p12. use this to trigger the voip notification manually.

```
apn push "<XXXXXX  XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX e8aafbd9>" -c VOIP.pem -m "Testing VoIP" -p
```

NOTE: Sometimes twilio tells invalid apns token. but still we are able to get the voip notification.

Comment: Once the app is ready for store submission, update the plist with “APS Environment: production. Is this step still required now a days? Doesn't xCode do it automatically?

Comment: I can confirm that xCode does it automatically. I can see aps-environment: production on iTunes Connect.

Comment: i do prefer adding it. bcoz while testing in sandbox we will be changing it to development. if we forget to change it back it might cause an issue. but apple by default will override for live application.

Comment: yes i know it. but in your case that is not at all a problem.

Comment: $ apn push "6eb7b82bd8a0a0762192" -c VOIP.pem -m "Testing VoIP" -p
Password: **********
1 push notification sent successfully. Didn't get anything on device though. Now what to check?

Comment: you have to pass valid device token like the above one with space separated.

Comment: $ apn push "<f6eb5168 xxx xx c85d478b 9b29adf4 xxx xx 490ce2cc>" -c VOIP.pem -m "Testing VoIP" -p
Password: **********
1 push notification sent successfully. Nothing received on the device.

Comment: which means the problem is with your certificates. if certificates are proper you will be receiving a VoiP notification. check voip is enabled, notification is enabled. while exporting .pl2 in keychain, you have to open the cert then export the one which is inside. do do right click on the cert itself. the prob is with you certificates. clear all of your local csr. create a fresh one. if notification receives then for sure twilio notification will be received. further we can continue in direct chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187372/discussion-between-dan-and-karthik).

Comment: is the answer helped you ?

Comment: Thanks for help Karthik. I couldn't find the exact issue but at least I've pinpointed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing with similar issue. The problem was with credentials token decoding.

For iOS 12 (and earlier version) + Xcode 10

```
let deviceToken = (credentials.token as NSData).description
```

For iOS 13

```
let deviceToken = credentials.token.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
```

More informations: https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift/issues/281

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the voice quickstart app manually and restarting. After doing so, I started being able to receive phone calls after downloading via Test Flight on my phone.

The issue comes from testing the app via Xcode on the same device that you're now trying to test via Test Flight.

I was running into the exact same problem. Even after following Karthik's answer, and creating a new iOS SDK Credential in the Twilio Console, and updating my server for the new credential SID, I still was getting the "Error - 52134 Invalid APNs device token".

I did some more digging, and found [this issue](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-ios/issues/304) on the Github page for twilio/voice-quickstart-ios repo.

Here is what the Twilio engineer said:

"Thanks for reaching out to us.

This is a commonly seen issue when the device is used previously with development entitlement and later in a production environment. We have observed that in this case the device token returned in the PushKit delegate method will be for the previous environment (development entitlement device token) when launching the TestFlight app for the first time. Although registration still works since both the device token format and the Push Credential SID are valid, but error will happen when Twilio tries to send the notification delivery request to APNS.

Ideally this will only happen to the dev devices and to resolve this you simply need to relaunch the TestFlight app then it should be able to receive incoming call notifications.

Hope this helps."

You still need to create the same Push Credentials in Twilio Console with the sandbox checkbox unchecked, and update the credential SID on the server.